# Requiring C++ DLL from Lua gives an error

Tags: c++, dll, lua, sdl-2

I am trying to compile C++ code to a DLL file to use with Lua. To do this, I am using Visual Studio 2022 with Windows 10. My goal is to use the Lua `require(modname)` function to require my DLL and use the C++ methods in Lua. For now the DLL and the main.lua files are in the same directory. What is actually happening is that I get an error message saying:

> error loading module 'lgf' from file 'lgf.dll': The specified module could not be found.

with the Lua code:

```
package.cpath = "?.dll;"..package.cpath
create = require("lgf")
```

My main.cpp file contains the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <window/include/window.hpp>
#include <font/include/font.hpp>
#include <image/include/image.hpp>
#include <keyboard/include/keyboard.hpp>
#include <mouse/include/mouse.hpp>
#include <rectangle/include/rectangle.hpp>

#include <lua/lua.hpp>

#define LIB

SDL_Window* sdlWin;
SDL_Renderer* sdlRen;

window win(sdlWin, sdlRen);

static const luaL_Reg lib[] = {
    {"create", window::create},
    {"isCloseRequested", window::isCloseRequested},
    {"sync", window::sync},
    {"update", window::update},
    {"setVSync", window::setVSync},
    {"setIcon", window::setIcon},
    {"clearScreen", window::clearScreen},
    {"render", window::render},
    {"windowChangeColor", window::changeColorRGB},
    {"close", window::close},

    {"createRectangle", rectangle::create},
    {"changeRectangleColor", rectangle::changeColor},
    {"drawRectangle", rectangle::draw},

    {"mouseButtonUp", Mouse::mouseButtonUp},
    {"mouseButtonDown", Mouse::mouseButtonDown},

    {"keyup", Keyboard::keyup},
    {"keydown", Keyboard::keydown},

    {"loadImage", ImageLoader::loadImage},
    {"drawImage", ImageLoader::drawImage},

    {"loadFont", FontLoader::loadFont},
    {"loadText", FontLoader::loadText},
    {"renderText", FontLoader::renderText},

    {NULL, NULL}
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int luaopen_lgf(lua_State* L) {
    luaL_newlib(L, lib);
    return 22;
}
```

I am creating a simple graphics library. My dependencies are SDL2 and (of course) Lua.

I have tried creating an entry point (main) for the file, and I still get the same message. Let me know if I should include my other .cpp files in here.

Comment: Try to build Lua from the sources using the same VS2022 and remove `extern "C"` from your module.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff it still says "The specified module could not be found."

Comment: You'll have to use [dependency walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see where the dll load fails and what the actual error is (use the Profile option on your executable and the tool will show you all loaded DLLs and related errors).

Comment: You haven't shown your `DllMain` function. Could the problem be there?